# SSRS Parameter value list always empty

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, sql-server-2019

I'm using the new Report Builder for SSRS in SQL Server 2019, and I'm trying to create a paginated report with one multi-value parameter.

I've given my report two datasets, both from the same shared Data Source. One data set is all the report data, and the other just return as distinct list of keys from the first dataset.

Both queries run and return their expected values in the query designer. However if I create a multivalue parameter and set the available values to a field in that query. I get a blank list every time, and the entire report is also blank, even though I don't have the report configured to do anything with that parameter yet.

[image: Parameter Settings]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? I am using the same cached sql login on the report, data source, and datasets, and the query definitely returns values.

If I remove the parameter from the report, then everything works as expected.

Comment: How many values would you say are returned by the parameter data set? Could it be that it's a lengthy list and it's thinking before returning values?

Comment: about 2500, but even it I change the query something dead simple that only returns two values, It does the same thing

Comment: Did you try deleting the parameter and creating again? Maybe delete, recreate using smaller data set, if that works then plug in the larger.

Comment: still no. Even if I make a dataset whose query is SELECT 'TEST VALUE' AS VALUE

Comment: In the second dataset's query, are you referencing a parameter derived from the first dataset?

Comment: Just a hunch, have you tried creating default values for the parameter just to test that the data is actually passing through? Sometimes with default values, I have to set the first default to an expression to get it to pass the parameter.

Comment: the default is set to the same dataset, because the default needs to be all selected